# /-/v1/search endpoint of public NPM Registry doesn't work properly

Tags: npm, repository, nexus

I’m trying to use the public npm registry API to get packages from my private **Nexus** repository and I have some issues.

Registry documentation: https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md#get-v1search

In the API I use **/-/v1/search/size=255&from=3** the **from** parameter doesn’t work properly and the API returns a random result, it seems like the system skips a random number of packages.

Does anybody know if it is possible to solve this problem?

I have tried this endpoint with different values: **/-/v1/search/size=255&from=3**